# Sea level rise prediction by zip code in the U.S. coasts

Tags: data, united-states, climate, sea-level-rise

I'm relatively new to GIS data and am working on a project on climate change. I can find online predictions of sea level rise by zip code in the U.S. East, West and Gulf Coasts (for example:  http://sealevel.climatecentral.org/) but I would like to know if there is public data available so that I could generate similar predictions in python or a similar language.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a bit of their work was based on NOAA's digital coast program, which means at least some of the supporting data should be open source and available from the US Government. You might want to check here: [coast.noaa.gov/digitalcoast](http://coast.noaa.gov/digitalcoast)